# How to correctly set up a cron job that runs a PHP script which sends an email?

Tags: php, email, cron

I've put together a PHP script that sends some content to a predefined email address and wanted to set up a cron job that would run that PHP script each day. Additionally, I've set it up to also send me an email each time the cron runs. 
I should mention that this script uses the PHP `mail()` function to send the email in html format and that I've tested if the script works by accessing directly through my browser's address bar.

The cron command:  `php /home/myuserid/public_html/projects/jobs/index.php`

Surprisingly, when the cron ran, I received the following error message through email:

***Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/sendmail line 15.
Content-type: text/html***

I'm not even sure where to start looking for the problem, so I need to ask: how do I correctly set up a simple cron job that runs a PHP scripts which sends an email using the `mail()` function?

Comment: There's not enough information in your post.  Does everything work when you run the script manually?  If so how are you running it?

Comment: @Matt Whipple It does work perfectly, when I run the script via the browser's address bar. Not sure how else to test it.

Comment: if you're expecting to run it through a web browser then you should be kicking it off using `curl` or `wget`.  It sounds like you're returning HTTP headers which are getting sent to the wrong output stream.  If it's not exposed publicly you could also try using `lynx` or something similar and then spend time adjusting the script for CLI use.  If you have headers you should remove them, or you could redirect `stdout` in the cron command.

Comment: I'm indeed using cURL to retrieve content from a job directory. I then  parse the returned HTML document, put together the email body with the interesting jobs list and send it. But I honestly don't understand what this has to do with the error thrown when the cron job runs.

Comment: If you wrote the code to be accessed through an HTTP request, then that's how it should be accessed in the cron job.  so rather than "php ${scriptFsPath}" you should be running something like "curl ${scriptUrl}".

Comment: You could also try the quick fix of adding " > /dev/null" to the end of your cron job.  This will discard the output but the script will still run. `php /home/myuserid/public_html/projects/jobs/index.php > /dev/null`

Comment: Also, in response to your first comment of not knowing how else to test it...you should be able to run _the same exact command that cron runs_. If it doesn't work manually it won't work scheduled.

Comment: I'm using cPanel, on a shared hosting server, so I don't have access to a cmd dialog (or at least that's what I know). Additionally, what I've tried was the " > /dev/null" extension to the command. What that did was to remove the "Content-type: text/html" from the error message that I receive through email. Now it's just "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/sendmail line 15.". So I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you try using `wget` in the cron job to just call the same URL you're using in your browser to test?

Comment: @Matt Whipple I didn't, but I've contacted my hosting provider and they've changed the cron command to php `/home/myuserid/public_html/projects/jobs/index.php 2> /dev/null` which did the trick. But I'm not sure why it did, because I'm not versed in this. If you know, please post an answer with an explanation and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted my hosting provider and they've changed the cron command themselves to `php /home/myuserid/public_html/projects/jobs/index.php 2> /dev/null`, which did the trick.
@Matt Whipple suggested a partial fix (i.e. adding `/dev/null` to the command line).

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say exactly what the problem is without looking at the script itself, but the underlying issue was that the output stream was being sent to the wrong place.  In a standard POSIX environment there are 2 standard output streams, standard output (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`).  When viewing the script in a web browser `stdout` will be passed to the browser and `stderr` will be handled by Apache and normally sent to a logger.

When calling from the command line this is different: they could be expected to print to the console (which is the standard `stdout`), but are dependent on things like the script and the CLI `php.ini`.  In your case the line referencing the `Content-Type` indicates that the output is being sent to the wrong location.  You can redirect the output using shell (normally BASH) redirection.  You use `>` for write and `>>` for append and you can also indicate the output stream where the default is `stdout` and `2` represents `stderr`.  The output can be sent anywhere such as a basic logging file, or if it is not needed at all it can be discarded by sending it to the special device `/dev/null`.

So....the provided solution of

`php /home/myuserid/public_html/projects/jobs/index.php 2> /dev/null`

runs your script while discarding errors sent to `stderr` which were previously getting sent to the wrong destination and causing some receiver to throw up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your server has a SMTP Server active. Plus if it's saying you have a concatenation problem then you've done something wrong along lines like;

```
$output = $string . " and " . $string;
```

or like this;

```
$output = "Hello";
$output .= " there!";
```

Comment: I have indeed done something like this to compose the email content, but no error is thrown when running the script through the browser's address bar...

Answer (score 0):

The method of running cron seems correct. There must be a problem with your mail sending. Your server may not support using `mail()` function. You can prefer smtp mail using [PhpMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/).

Try setting headers:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: It does work perfectly, when I run the script via the browser's address bar. So the problem isn't with using `mail()` at all. Or at least it's not something very visible to me.

Comment: Did you set content type for email at headers. Check out my update.

Comment: The headers were already set: `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Try adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8') ;` to top of your php page.

Comment: And also you can force php to set utf-8 as default charset in .htaccess file with `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Comment: You are using cpanel, aren't you? Because I don't know other platforms but your cron usage may not work on Plesk.